# CSS background color not showing up?

Tags: html, css

I made two classes in which one is main and other one is a child div. In main div I give width of 100% background color:red and in child div I give width 100% and background blue and margin top 100px. But in browser red color is not showing up. If I use float in main div then color is appearing in browser but the main class already have width 100% so we are not supposed to give float element in it.

```
<style>

.main {width:100%; background-color:#FF0000}

.child { width:100%; margin-top:100px; background:#0000FF}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="main">   
    <div class="child">asfda</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the fiddle:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uT7Vv/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uT7Vv/embedded/result/

Comment: This answer would be better if the code was available here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your Child div overlap on your main Div

needs to give height in main div .Try this

```
<style>

.main {width:100%; background-color:#FF0000;height:50px;}

.child { width:100%; margin-top:100px; background:#0000FF}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="main">

<div class="child">asfda</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your margins are [collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). You can fix this by using `padding` on the parent element instead:

```css
.main {
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.child {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}​
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2xZGV/)

Comment: @JitenderChand: See the link. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins Adjacent margins collapse under certain circumstances.